# Sometimes my terminal screws up newlines after killing a process

Tags: macos, terminal, newlines

When I fire up a new terminal, this is usually what it can look like:

```
$ echo "test"; echo "blaat"
test
blaat
```

But sometimes after having run a process in the terminal that I killed with SIGKILL, my terminal starts doing weird:

```
$ echo "test"; echo "blaat"
test
    blaat
```

It's like newlines don't start on the left any more, but on the position the last line ended.

Which sucks for example when doing:

```
$ ls -1 /
Applications
            Developer
                     Library
                            Network
                                   System
                                         Users
                                              Volumes
                                                     bin
                                                        cores
                                                             dev
                                                                home
                                                                    lost+found
                                                                              net
                                                                                 opt
                                                                                    private
                                                                                           sbin
                                                                                               usr
                                                                                                  etc
                                                                                                     tmp
                                                                                                        var
```

I don't know enough about terminal magic to understand why this happens, but if I could easily fix it without having to close my terminal and restart it, It'd be awesome.

I'm on Mac OS X running zsh in iTerm2, but I'm pretty sure this happens on Terminal.app as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. Running this command fixes the terminal back to normal:

```
$ stty sane
```